# Changing the font family in Flutter when using ThemeData.dark() or ThemeData.light()

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

I'm trying to set the font of my `MaterialApp`. Since I'm using the dark theme, I'd like to just use `copyWith` and then change the `fontFamily`. However, `copyWith` doesn't have an option to change the `fontFamily`.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    fontFamily: 'MyFontFamily',
  ),
```

> The named parameter 'fontFamily' isn't defined.

How do I keep the dark theme but also change the font family? (Same problem with `ThemeData.light()`.)

*I found a solution and am posting below.*

Answer (score 27):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart) for `ThemeData.light()` and `ThemeData.dark()`, you can see that all it does is set the `brightness` value:

```dart
/// A default light blue theme.
///
/// This theme does not contain text geometry. Instead, it is expected that
/// this theme is localized using text geometry using [ThemeData.localize].
factory ThemeData.light() => ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light);

/// A default dark theme with a teal secondary [ColorScheme] color.
///
/// This theme does not contain text geometry. Instead, it is expected that
/// this theme is localized using text geometry using [ThemeData.localize].
factory ThemeData.dark() => ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark);
```

That means to solve your problem you don't need to bother with `ThemeData.light()` or `ThemeData.dark()`. Just create a new `ThemeData` and set the `brightness` yourself in addition to the `fontFamily`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    fontFamily: 'MyFontFamily',
  ),
```

Answer (score 6):

With flutter 3 & above it's much easier to change fontFamily globally with themes `ThemeData.light()` and `ThemeData.dark()`, all what you need to do is to set `TextTheme` through `Typography`. `Typography().black` is used in Light Theme & `Typography().white` in dark theme.
In your case for **dark theme**:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    textTheme: Typography().white.apply(fontFamily: 'MyFontFamily'),
  ),
```

And for **light theme** use `Typography().black`

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    textTheme: Typography().black.apply(fontFamily: 'MyFontFamily'),
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Since, all you're doing is setting the `brightness`, I think the easier way would be to just use `DefaultTextStyle`.

```dart
DefaultTextStyle(
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'YourFontFamily',
  ),
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```

Comment: Interesting. So you'd wrap the whole widget tree with this?

Comment: Yes, except for setting it in the `MaterialApp`, it's better to use `Theme` there. For elsewhere, `DefaultTextStyle` should be the way to go. There is no need to use a `Theme` widget (just for changing the `TextStyle`).

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUX1uVCewvk