# Flutter: Change font family in ThemeData with .copyWith

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I know that you can define a new `ThemeData` object with your own font like this:

```
ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Roboto')
```

However, I want to copy an existing `ThemeData` by using the `copyWith` method:

```
ThemeData.dark().copyWith(...)
```

Sadly, there is no argument `fontFamiliy` in `copyWith`. I only want to change the fontFamily and not define an entirely new `TextTheme`.

How do I copy an existing `ThemeData` and change its font familiy?

Comment: One thing really bad about Flutter is theme. It's such a mess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    textTheme: ThemeData.dark().textTheme.apply(
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        ),
    primaryTextTheme: ThemeData.dark().textTheme.apply(
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        ),
);
```

If you look at the sources, it's the same thing:

[image]

This is about the same thing: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41276

I don't know why exactly you needed to copy font, but sometimes it makes sense to set fontFamily in theme MaterialApp. About this there is in: [Changing the font family in Flutter when using ThemeData.dark() or ThemeData.light()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68810575/changing-the-font-family-in-flutter-when-using-themedata-dark-or-themedata-lig)

Comment: Too bad there is no more straight-forward way to specify the fontFamily when not using ThemeData default constructor. But at least there is a solution.